# Binary output using C on PIC microprocessor for MIDI output

Tags: c, midi, pic

so I am creating a project which requires a binary output to function. I have a series of IF statements to determine what the output is and all is well here. The issue is I am using a PIC microcontroller, 16F877 and programming in C.
I am using RS232 to send information straight into a midi controller with about 8 values of notes and 8 values of volume (8x8 set of options).

I am also using proteus and CCS to program.

My issue is : how do i create the MIDI output in binary?
I am aware of all the binary values but I am uncertain as to how I create a "midi friendly" output.

***EDIT: Added sample code as per request:***

```
#include <16F877.h>
TRISB=1; //sets all tris in portB to 1, to allow as inputs

TRISD=1; //sets all tris in portD to 1, to allow as inputs

TRISC.RC6=0; //sets trisC port 6 to 0, to allow as an output

#use rs232(baud=9600,parity=N,xmit=STDOUT,rcv=None,bits=8,stream=PORT1,float_high)
// initialises RS232 and configures for transmision
#use delay(crystal=4MHz)
// crystal at 4MHz is used (XT MODE)

#define X1  PIN_B0 //names pin B0 as X1
#define X2  PIN_B1 //names pin B1 as X2
#define X3  PIN_B2 //names pin B2 as X3
#define X4  PIN_B3 //names pin B3 as X4
#define X5  PIN_B4 //names pin B4 as X5
#define X6  PIN_B5 //names pin B5 as X6
#define X7  PIN_B6 //names pin B6 as X7
#define X8  PIN_B7 //names pin B7 as X8

#define STDOUT  PIN_C6 // Names pin C6 as STDOUT

#define Y1  PIN_D0 //names pin D0 as Y1
#define Y2  PIN_D1 //names pin D1 as Y2
#define Y3  PIN_D2 //names pin D2 as Y3
#define Y4  PIN_D3 //names pin D3 as Y4
#define Y5  PIN_D4 //names pin D4 as Y5
#define Y6  PIN_D5 //names pin D5 as Y6
#define Y7  PIN_D6 //names pin D6 as Y7
#define Y8  PIN_D7 //names pin D7 as Y8

char xout;
char yout;

int main (void)
 { 
   if(B0==1) //if B0 is 1, sets xout to "A"
   {
      xout='A';
   }
   if(B1==1) //if B1 is 1, sets xout to "B"
   {
      xout='B';
   }
   if(B2==1) //if B2 is 1, sets xout to "C"
   {
      xout='C';
   }
   if(B3==1) //if B3 is 1, sets xout to "D"
   {
      xout="D";
   }
   if(B4==1) //if B4 is 1, sets xout to "E"
   {
      xout='E';
   }
   if(B5==1) //if B5 is 1, sets xout to "F"
   {
      xout='F';
   }
   if(B6==1) //if B6 is 1, sets xout to "G"
   {
      xout='G';
   }
   if(B7==1) //if B7 is 1, sets xout to "H"
   {
      xout='H';
   }
   if(D0==1) //if D0 is 1, sets yout to "A"
   {
      yout='A';
   }
   if(D1==1) //if D1 is 1, sets yout to "B"
   {
      yout='B';
   }
   if(D2==1) //if D2 is 1, sets yout to "C"
   {
      yout='C';
   }
   if(D3=1) //if D3 is 1, sets yout to "D"
   {
      yout='D';
   }
   if(D4==1) //if D4 is 1, sets yout to "E"
   {
      yout='E';
   }
   if(D5==1) //if D5 is 1, sets yout to "F"
   {
      yout='F';
   }
   if(D6==1) //if D6 is 1, sets yout to "G"
   {
      yout='G';
   }
   if(D7==1) //if D7 is 1, sets yout to "H"
   {
      yout='H';
   }


   printf("%c,%c", xout yout); //outputs xout and yout for display on a screen
```

In place of the Letters (they were just for demonstrating an actual outputso that I could progress to midi) would be the binary code, the printf would instead be outputting the midi value determined in the IF statements

***EDIT 2: further insight***

I'll be essentially using an an 8x8 grid of "switches" (using visible lights as means of interfacing) the x axis controls the note, Y axis controls the volume. I require only one output and that will be directly into a midi controller via 5 pin- DIN

Comment: Are you asking for the midi protocol on the wire? https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~craig/articles/linuxmidi/misc/essenmidi.html

Comment: that would surely be helpful (as I'm not actually at that stage) but what i am asking for is how i actually send an output in binary format

Comment: Please also add the actual code to the question.

Comment: What do you mean, "MIDI output in binary?"  You are sending bytes serially though a port.  A byte is composed of a series of bits.  It is binary by definition.

Comment: This site looks useful: http://www.music-software-development.com/midi-tutorial.html

Comment: Ah you connected some keys to input pins of the PIC and now you want to "MIDI" play?

Comment: essentially, yes.
there is an 8x8 grid of "switches" the x axis controls the note, Y axis controls the volume. I require only one output and that will be directly into a midi controller via 5 pin- DIN

Comment: You are aware that you need to send 2 messages? "Note on" command when the key is pressed, then "Note off" when the key is released. The volume can be coded into the "velocity" parameter of those commands, which have 2 parameters of 1 byte/char each.

Comment: I don't understand, you tagged your question with C++ yet in your post you say you are writing in C.  Which is it?  They are two separate languages?  Which language do you want code presented?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews AFAIK, there is no C++ on (small) PICs.

Comment: You need to correct your program:  `"A"` is a *string*, more than one character and you are assigning to a single character variable.  Try using single quotes, `'A'`.

Comment: sorry thomas, no explanation of why I included C++ asides I know theyre similar and I was taught C and C++ alongside within same parameters in visual basic and wasnt thinking. ill try and remove the tag.

Comment: MIDI PROJECTS Utilizing the PIC 16F877 http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/Music_technology/midi_projects/projects.htm

Comment: Also, remember, `=` means assignment, `==` means equal to.  In your `if` statements you are performing assignments.

Comment: Your code is not using the `x` and `y` variables.  Is this a mistake or something for future use?

Comment: You may want to experiment with reading the ports as an 8-bit quantity instead of accessing each pin (bit) separately.

Comment: You've got a logic issue here.  If B1==1 and B2==1, `xout` will be assigned the value for `B2==1` even though `B1==1` as well.  You may want to use a character array and one letter for each bit; append the letters as you go through the `if` tree.

Comment: yes the x and y is for future use, I stripped down the code for a more understandable (in my eyes) variant to help explain my issue, also thanks for the heads up in my code errors :)

in response to user2225104, yes I am aware, ive done a lot of background research but have been unable to find how i program a pic in C to output a binary command,i need to know how it is that i send that binary instruction code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably start out with only 2 commands (NoteOn, NoteOff) and then proceed as required.

Below, a sample "architecture" which I would probably use to get my feet wet.
As you need to keep track of "note on" and "note off" operations, I added the global "state" array. The first index changes between current state and old state in an alternating way. For starters this just might be enough.

8 slots for your 8 keys. The value could be the "volume" code in case the key is presed. It is KEY_OFF in case no key for that tone was pressed.

```
#define KEY_OFF 0x80  // command parameters only use lower 7 bits...
static uint8_t state[2][8];

static void Configure()
{   // Do what you need to do in terms of initializing pins, serial port, etc...

}

static void UpdateState(uint8_t index)
{
    // read pins into the global state variable at first index "index"
    // Not pressed "tones" get value "OFF".
    // TIP: later, you could consider to use PIC 
    // "interrupt on change" features 
    // to save power. 
    // Tip: Depending on the types of your keys and your circuitry,
    // you might run into "bouncing keys" problems.
    // But the fact, that you send your serial messages synchronously
    // gives your keys some time to "settle", which might be enough.
}

// ROM based lookup table
// TODO: fill in correct values for your note-key to note-to-play mapping.
static const uint8_t notes[8] =
{ 0x01
, 0x01
, 0x01
, 0x01
, 0x01
, 0x01
, 0x01
, 0x01
};

static const uint8_t velocities[8] =
{
    // TODO: 8 entries mapping your "volume key" code to a MIDI "velocity" code.
};

#define DEFAULT_CHANNEL 0x00 // 16 channels available in midi... 0x00..0x0F

static void SerialSend(uint8_t count, const uint8_t * message)
{  // TODO: Implement sending the message on Rs232...
   // TIP: Use the flag "tx buffer EMPTY" before you write next byte.
   for( uint8_t i = 0; i < count; ++i )
   {
       while( !TXEMPTY ); // TODO: look up correct name ...
       TX = message[i]; // TODO: look up correct name...
   }
}

// Assuming to use only channel 0 here...
static void SendNoteOff(uint8_t note)
{
    // TODO: find out if NoteOff needs a "real" velocity value...
    uint8_t midiCmd[3] = { 0x80|DEFAULT_CHANNEL, notes[note], 0x00  };
    SerialSend(3, midiCmd);
}

static void SendNoteOn(uint8_t note, uint8_t velocity)
{
    uint8_t midiCmd[3] = { 0x90 | DEFAULT_CHANNEL, notes[note], velocities[velocity] };
    SerialSend(3, midiCmd);
}

// Named it emain() as it is in some random file of mine which already has a main ;)
void emain()
{
    Configure();
    uint8_t current = 0;
    uint8_t old = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        UpdateState(current);
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            uint8_t os = state[old][i];
            uint8_t cs = state[current][i];
            if (os != cs )
            {
                if (0x00 != (cs & KEY_OFF))
                {
                    SendNoteOff(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    SendNoteOn(i, cs);
                }
            }
        }
        old = current;
        current = (current + 1) % 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're suggesting to use Hex instead of sending in binary? this is an acceptable workaround which i will probably be using thanks :)

but rather than through hex, is it possible to send (for a C note with a value of 60) rather than 0x3C, to send for example: 00111100?

I ask this mostly out of interest at this point, but also for future reference and possibly an alternative approach for this to discuss in a report.

I would upvote your comment, but thanks to some people downvoting my question - for whatever reason i fail to understand at this point, my reputation is only at 4 :(

Comment: It does not matter how you write literal values. In decimal or hex or binary or octal. In the end, you describe the value a variable shall have, such as a byte. If you write ``unsigned char x = 42;`` or if you write ``unsigned char x = 0x2A;``, the value in x is the same. So pick whatever you can read easily. In case of those Midi commands using hex is useful as the commands are somehow restricted by conventions, such as "parameters are only 7 bit wide. I.e. values 0x80 and bigger would be bad. Easy to see in hex, harder to see in decimal. Well a wee bit harder.

Comment: Thanks user 2225104 :)

Just in case anyone else is interested - I have found a useful identifier - namely int8, it creates an integer a single byte long, perfect for one piece of midi output - it is my understanding i can output that value and it will create an output in the bite i want (i.e. if 60 is 00111100, int8 60 will output that byte)